# Extract log files between delimiters, sort according to Keywords, and date range timestamp

Tags: text-processing

I want to extract logs in between delimiters(`+++` and `++-`) like:

```
+++ HOST 2022-02-01 15:25:41 mngt   #000000 0-0-1 >

A  MANUAL ERROR=42019

   some=DATA0, /n/pslv5001/SOURCE/file22.src/cc/Player.C AT LINE 69420

   THE SIGTRAN LICENSE KEY ON HOST HOST-0-0-7 DOES NOT EXIST.

   ERROR 4

   THE TEST DONE SUCCESSFULLY

   END OF REPORT #000069++-
```

Suppose there are multiple logs like above, need to sort logs that contains multiple keywords and date range timestamp.
for example, I should be able to sort logs that contain keywords such as "ERROR", "SUCCESSFULLY" and any other keyword(s) in the log with timestamp 2022-01-25 00:00:00 till 2022-02-01 23:59:59.

Comment: sed -n ‘/+++/,/++-/p’ file.log Should get you started but it would help if you’d provide a more comprehensive source (including entries you would wish to exclude) and an exact output you would expect from that source

Comment: As a start, get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins and install GNU awk if you don't already have it. Then try to solve your problem and then post a question including your code attempt if you need help.